# Ways to determine approximate magnitude of crosstalk between PCB layers

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers, crosstalk

Is there any basic methods to calculate crosstalk between different layers in a multilayer PCB. I am not after anything exact just a way to grasp the magnitude of the issue.

The situation I am trying to solve is in a 4 layer space constrained PCB with a stackup of Signal-Ground-Power-Signal, on my bottom layer I have a number of differential +/- 10V Signals max freq 1KHz. On the power layer above these traces I have a power trace with a current varying between 0-200mA with a minimum rise time of approximately 0.1ms, the trace for the return current is directly adjacent.

Assuming there is no other way I can route my PCB how can I go about getting a feel for what kind of affect a step in my current can affect my signals.

Other data

Signal Output impedance <100 ohms

- Signal Input impedance approx 10k ohms
- Signal trace width 12mil, trace separation 12mil
- Power trace width 40mil, separation 20mill
- Copper Weight 1oz
- Outer plane separation 0.2mm
- Inner plane separation 1.2mm
- Length of parallel run 75mm

Comment: check out the PCB Toolkit by Saturn PCB Design Inc.

Comment: Why have I never run across this tool before, it looks pretty cool, any recommendations how I can get it to work for my stackup which is effectively two signals above a ground plane.

Comment: So are you saying you've got a current-carrying pair on the 'power'-inner layer, and a signal diff-pair on the bottom layer, and they're both running parallel to each other for 75mm?  But what's the lateral separation between them?

Comment: On top of each other I know it's bad that's why I am trying to evaluate this vs running wires.

Comment: I recommend Hyperlynx SI, though it is very expensive software there is a trial version. https://www.mentor.com/pcb/hyperlynx/signal-integrity/

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the output from Hyperlynx: http://s13.postimg.org/hatkk8jqv/hyperlynx.png . The "loops" show the effect of the em field emanating from each trace on surrounding traces. To avoid crosstalk altogether, these "loops" should not touch any other surrounding traces/pairs: http://s17.postimg.org/i6zz7rzu7/hyperlynx2.png

Answer (score 1):

As @derstrom8 suggested, there are better tools for doing this, but tend to be expensive & aimed at pros.  I vaguely remember there is a FOSS field-solver tool out there somewhere, but can't remember.  But if I interpret your PCB stack-up figures correctly, you may be able to approximate your situation with the Saturn tool I mentioned:

[image: Saturn PCB Toolkit]

If you set it to 'stripline' mode where you're calculating crosstalk of 2 tracks sandwiched within 2 planes, and then set the distance of the bottom plane effectively to infinity (500mm) because that doesn't exist in this scenario, then set H1 to the gap between your 2 inner planes (where the lower plane is your power track on the inner-bottom, right?), and H2 to the gap between bottom-layer & bottom-plane (what you describe sounds like a typical 4-layer stack-up), I see -84dB, or 1.25mV.

Perhaps with that rough idea you can use your input-impedance & knowledge of the broader system to work out how significant this may or may not be.

Comment: How can I relate this coupled voltage to an input impedance, what would the impedance of the coupling better. I assume the higher the input impedance the more effect it will have.

Comment: hang on - my answer isn't right at all!  i mistook your +/-10V to be what the PSU is doing, but that's just your signal swing.  So your PSU is switching 0-200mA, but what's its voltage?

Comment: This particular traces is out of a current regulator, that will drive a signal somewhere between 0-200mA to a maximum of 15V. While not technically a power rail I though it should be separated out from my signal layers.

Comment: 15V - ok, so that's not much different to the 20V I put in based on your +/-10V anyway, so the result won't be hugely different, 0.94mV.

Comment: So is crosstalk always a certain induced voltage, for some reason I thought of it as injecting a certain amount of power into the adjacent line, which then translates into certain voltages via the impedance.

Comment: i think you're just looking at Ohm's Law the wrong way around :).  the voltage induced on the adjacent conductor will cause a certain current to flow (additional or less, that's just polarity) - how much current depends on the resistance/impedance of the circuit it finds itself on, and from there: V x I = P.

Comment: That's what I was asking so the crosstalk is a fixed voltage not a fixed amount of energy.

Comment: I think it's neither.  The analogy would be more like the interference comes from an amplifier with a non-negligible output impedance;  it attempts to assert a certain voltage; but if the target trace has low impedance, then you won't be able to assert a high voltage.  The energy is not predetermined either, because the intensity of the wave depends on the coupling.  The point is:  the tools (simulators) determine the actual parameters; once you have those, it doesn't matter from which side you look at Ohm's law (you don't need to worry about which one is cause and which one is effect).